# What makes a console application project

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between a console application project and a class library project. That is, what would be needed to make a class library project be able to output to console. The question is theoretical, i am not i need of doing this so tips on how i could do it otherwise wont be nescessary.

Comment: A class library project doesn't contain a static Main entry point  class which a console project does.

Comment: Oh so its just a matter of adding the Main entry point class and changing the project setting to Console Application instead of Class Library as Output Type i realised now. THANKS!